# SQL Inverse JOIN Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS-SQL Server

```
Table A (Study_ID,Issue_Id)  
          XX,1  
          BB,2   

Table B (Study_ID,System_Id)  
         XX,User1  
         BB,User2  
         XX,User2    

View V : (Issue_Id,System_Id)  
           2,User1
```

View V should give all Issues from `Table A`, for System_Id `X`, which are not in `Table B` for the combination of `Study` and `SytemID`

The purpose is, The table A has Issues(Issue_Id), which are tied to Study(Study_id). If A user User1 logs in into system he should be able to see all issues in table A apart from the ones which have study_id for which the user isn't having rights. Table B indicates the StudyId's for which the user has no rights

How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

Comment: Hi Varun, You need to show what have you tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: A JOIN is simply a set of rows that have matching values in both tables. If this is the Venn Diagram, then you want a query that shows all of the values not matched by either table. However, the catch is matching this result set by the System_ID numbers. We would call this an OUTER join. Is this correct?

Comment: You are going to have to explain your question a little better. What are you trying to achieve? Is there supposed to be some connection between Issue_ID and System_ID? I am very unclear on why 2, User1 is your desired output, if that is indeed your desired output

Comment: @kbball Issue_id and system_id are not really connected. The purpose is, The table A has Issues(Issue_Id), which are tied to Study(Study_id). If A user User1 logs in into system he should be able to see all issues in table A apart from the ones which have study_id for which the user isnt having rights. Table B indicates the studyId's for which the user has no rights

Comment: Why is your desired output: 2, User1?

Comment: @kbball because User1 should be able to access all the issue_id's but since IssueId 1 has the study XX and table B has XX-User1 by the virtue of that IssueId becomes hidden for User1, for User2 both the StudyIds are hidden so he doesnt shows up in View V

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a list of all the combinations of Study_IDs AND System_IDs and then by a left join you can see whether or not the combination exists.

I'm a bit confused as to your comment about user rights. Is this more of a database issue, or is using a `AND System_ID = 'User1'` in the `WHERE` statement a solution?

```
WITH T_A AS (SELECT *
             FROM ( VALUES ('XX', 1)
                         , ('BB', 2)
                    ) x (Study_ID, Issue_ID)
            )
    , T_B AS (SELECT * 
              FROM ( VALUES ('XX', 'User1')
                          , ('BB', 'User2')
                          , ('XX', 'User2')
                    ) x ( Study_ID, System_ID)
             )

SELECT Issue_ID, USERS.System_ID
FROM T_A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT System_ID FROM T_B) USERS
ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN T_B
ON T_A.Study_ID = T_B.Study_ID
AND USERS.System_ID = T_B.System_ID
WHERE T_B.Study_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one way to do it:

```
select * from a
 except
 select * from b
```

Comment: this only works when the columns are the same which they are not. and it will not get his desired results as defined in View V